# How to make resolvconf append nameservers to the list instead of prepending them?

Tags: arch-linux, dns, openvpn, resolvconf

I'm trying to configure OpenVPN to update DNS-servers as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#DNS). That seems to work, but `resolvconf` prepends nameservers (and also search domains) to the list of existing nameservers. How can I make it append stuff to the end (i.e. give lower priority to these settings)?

Comment: Word of caution: the last search domain setting is the only one that's used. Therefore it has the highest priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvconf prioritizes nameserver addresses according to interface type. The priority can be changed by updating either the [`/etc/interface-order`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/interface-order.5.html) file or `/etc/resolvconf.conf`. For example, to make sure nameservers for `eno1` have a higher priority, add this line to `/etc/resolvconf.conf`:

`interface_order="lo* eno*"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `resolv.conf.head` and `resolv.conf.tail` files to add lines before and after the content generated by `resolvconf`

Answer (score 1):

use `name_servers_append` instead of `name_servers`

Answer (score 0):

When you add nameservers and search domains to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and then run `sudo resolvconf -u` it will append you records to etc/resolv.conf.